# Semivariance of variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, statistics

I'm new with sql and I struggle with such a problem. Let's suppose I have a table like this:

```
Date          Value   
2014-01-01    1248.56
2014-01-02    1247.24
2014-01-03    1245.82
2014-01-04    1252.07
...
```

All I want to do is count semivariance of variable 'Value'.
Semivariance only takes into account those records which are less than the average of the sample. So basically it is just a transformartion of simply variance. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
Table1
WHERE Value < (SELECT AVG(Value) FROM Table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need avg value then you can use such code.

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    date DATE,
    value NUMERIC(10,2)
)

INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('2014-01-01'   , 1248.56 ),
('2014-01-02'   ,    1247.24),
('2014-01-03'   ,    1245.82),
('2014-01-04'   ,    1252.07);


SELECT * FROM #test a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT AVG(value) avg_value FROM #test)  b
WHERE a.value < b.avg_value
```